# Building PHP5.6.18 on Arch Linux: windows test not skipped despite PHP_OS check

Tags: php, archlinux, php-5.6

## Short version

Why does this unmodified code from the official PHP 5.6.18 release:

```
--SKIPIF--
<?php
if (phpversion() < "5.3.0") { die('SKIP php version so lower.'); }
if (!extension_loaded('openssl')) { die('ext/openssl required'); }
if(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) != 'WIN' ) {
        die('skip windows only test');
}
?>
```

... not cause a windows-only test to be skipped when I'm building the PHP package on Arch Linux?

## Long version

I'm trying to build PHP5.6.18 using the PKGBUILD from the official Arch Build System. Here's what I've done:

1. `git clone git://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git`
2. I went through the [git history of the php package](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/log/trunk?h=packages/php), and identified [this commit](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/commit/trunk?h=packages/php&id=46b590bc37f1b24647d315d6196574c4316713ce) as the best starting point - basically the last commit before the uprev to PHP7. So, I cd into `packages`, and `git checkout` that commit ID.
3. I updated the PKGBUILD like this:

   - set `pkgver=5.6.18`
   - set `pkgrel=1`
   - set the first md5sum to `'177ba962557795866ae331ad4ad99bba'`
4. [setup clean chroot for building](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DeveloperWiki:Building_in_a_Clean_Chroot) (this reduced the test failures from 2-3 to 1)
5. Build php: `makechrootpkg -c -r $CHROOT` (in the directory with the `PKGBUILD` file.

The build works fine, but I get the following test failure:

```
Number of tests : 6651              6180
Tests skipped   :  471 (  7.1%) --------
Tests warned    :    1 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests failed    :    1 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Expected fail   :    9 (  0.1%) (  0.1%)
Tests passed    : 6169 ( 92.8%) ( 99.8%)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Time taken      :   45 seconds
...
FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
mixed stream_socket_enable_crypto(resource $stream , bool $enable [, int $crypto_type [, resource $session_stream
]] ) ; [ext/standard/tests/streams/stream_socket_enable_crypto-win32.phpt]
=====================================================================

=====================================================================
WARNED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Bug #70172 - Use After Free Vulnerability in unserialize() [ext/standard/tests/serialize/bug70172.phpt] (warn: XFA
IL section but test passes)
=====================================================================
```

OK, so the `win32` already looks suspicious in the filename, and a look at the file contents indeed suggests that the test should be skipped on Linux:

```
--TEST--
mixed stream_socket_enable_crypto(resource $stream , bool $enable [, int $crypto_type [, resource $session_stream ]] ) ;
...
--SKIPIF--
<?php
if (phpversion() < "5.3.0") { die('SKIP php version so lower.'); }
if (!extension_loaded('openssl')) { die('ext/openssl required'); }
if(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) != 'WIN' ) {
        die('skip windows only test');
}
?>
```

Note the `PHP_OS` related check. So, I'm thinking, maybe PHP_OS is somehow getting the wrong value. So, I:

1. Manually go into the build chroot: `arch-nspawn $CHROOT/$USER/`
2. Add `echo substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)`
   to the beginning of that test (just under the `<?php` in the `--FILE--` section, and in the actual `stream_socket_enable_crypto-win32.php` file)
3. Re-run it using the `stream_socket_enable_crypto-win32.sh` script in the same directory, I indeed see the expected `Lin` output.

Why is this test not skipped? I'm really confused. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, for now I'll just delete the test in the `prepare()` section of the `PKGBUILD` file:

```
prepare() {
        cd ${srcdir}/${pkgbase}-${pkgver}
        # ....
        # add this line:
        rm ./ext/standard/tests/streams/stream_socket_enable_crypto-win32.phpt
}
```

Comment: As this is a workaround rather than a proper fix, I won't mark this as the answer quite yet, see if anyone has a better idea/solution/root cause.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if M01 would let us know the name of the PKGBUILD file he edited so i could take a look at that as well.

But until then just open up this file:

```
/usr/src/php/ext/standard/tests/streams/stream_socket_enable_crypto-win32.phpt
```

and find this line as shown above as well.

And just comment out the line, if anyone is still running php 5.3 they should be tarballed and feathered anyway lol..

```
  //commented out by dave due to bug and should be skipped
 //if (phpversion() < "5.3.0") { die('SKIP php version so lower.'); }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just the [main php PKGBUILD file](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/php) in e.g. `/var/abs/extra/php/PKGBUILD` (if using ABS), which builds a whole slew of php related packages.